# python datetime function for different type of timezone

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to write a function different type of time zone. In this example I am in Ontario and want to winnipeg time.

def winnipeg_time():

```
x = datetime.datetime.now('America/Winnipeg')
print ('x')
```

Error I get :  tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify timezone as a string. A `datetime.timezone` object is required. Example:

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

> datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 20, **20**, 33, 44, 991250)

```
datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=1)))
```

> datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 20, **19**, 33, 29, 303461,
>   tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)))

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a `tzinfo` subclass by using `gettz()`. Another option to consider is to use `astimezone()` to specify the time zone.

Here's examples with those 2 options:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from dateutil.tz import tz

aw = pytz.timezone('America/Winnipeg')
x = datetime.now().astimezone(aw)
print(f'The pytz datetime in Winnipeg tz is {x}')

x2 = datetime.now(tz.gettz('America/Winnipeg'))
print(f'The gettz datetime in Winnipeg tz is {x2}')
```

Results:

```
The pytz datetime in Winnipeg tz is 2020-04-20 13:54:27.600227-05:00
The gettz datetime in Winnipeg tz is 2020-04-20 13:54:27.600544-05:00
```